# Are these on-topic? Request for link to refugee resettlement numbers + UN $ figures

Tags: support, scope

**Thanks to feedback provided, I will attempt to rewrite my query to fit the site better.**

I am looking for a table of figures of # Syrian refugees accepted per capita, by country.

What I've found so far: # international refugees accepted per capita, but only the top 20 or so, and it was from two years ago.  (http://ccrweb.ca/en/how-generous-is-canada)  I would like to find something similar but more up to date and specific to Syrian refugees.  If it has more than 20 countries, so much the better.  I'm especially interested to see how the U.S. compares to other developed nations.

Is something like that on topic for this site?

I'd also like to ask for a table showing how much is contributed to the U.N., country by country, compared to their fair share, with an explanation of how the fair share is calculated.  I suppose this should be a separate question?

What's a good way to leave the question open for responders to contribute analytical thoughts, beyond just a link to a table of figures?

Answer (score 4):

> I'd also like to ask for a table showing how much is contributed to the U.N., country by country, compared to their fair share, with an explanation of how the fair share is calculated.
>
> And then, may I ask for a succinct analysis of why the U.S. lags so far behind so many other countries, in both of those measures?

That seems to be assuming something, that the US "lags...far behind".  The US is the single largest contributor to the UN, at 22% overall.  The US makes up 16% of the world's economy by [GDP](https://www.statista.com/statistics/270267/united-states-share-of-global-gross-domestic-product-gdp/).  By that simple definition, the US pays a more than fair share.

That kind of question is going to be problematic and draw close votes for being overly opinionated.  It isn't looking for information.  It feels more like it's trying to frame the debate in such a way as to validate an existing opinion.

[Country by country contributions](http://www.un.org/en/ga/contributions/budget.shtml) to the UN are available through Google (click the PDF for the appropriate year).  It's unclear why you would need this site to do your Google search for you.

Also, if I'm reading your question right, you seem to be linking asylum seekers from Syria to UN payments, and those are two separate issues.  Reasons why the US has a low resettlement rate for Syrian asylum seekers do not necessarily have anything to do with why some countries pay more per some measure than the US does.  Contrast with something like military spending.  Also completely unrelated.  Or the number of Cuban former refugees in the US.  Or the number of undocumented immigrants who may or may not be refugees from their Central or South American country.

Answer (score 0):

So, It sounds like you found some information, but it wasn't enough, and then you found some other information, and that wasn't enough, and so on.  This is a red flag that your proposed question might be too broad.

It sounds like you have all the data you need, but you want it all in a specific table and aggregated in a specific way, and since your gripe with the first resource was "but only the top 20 or so", it sounds like you want it to be comprehensive too.

If I saw that question in the Close queue, I'm not quite sure what I'd do with it.   It's kinda in a grey area where you are asking for a finite amount of data, but your needs are so specific that it sounds like a more generalized answer won't do.